# Beautifulsoup cannot parse htm created in word?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, encoding

I created a .htm file (the stripped type without a data folder) in MS Word 365. I used to create those types of files all the time and load them into a .py script all the time using bs4, but now it doesn't work for some reason. That might've been caused by me writing a previous version to a new file with `errors='ignore'`, but I am not certain. Now when I read it in, there is a bunch of spaces in between everything, so I'm guessing there is some kind of whitespace character that doesn't exist in the encoding that I'm using to read the file in?

Anyways, this is the [link to the public repository where I keep my project](https://github.com/p3rAsperaAdAstra/TOPAS-Param-Tables-public-):

In there, the minimal working example is contained within the FOR_SO.py script. The .htm file is called "broken.htm". I'm gonna post the minimal code here as well, but the file is too big to upload here.

How did I break it so badly?

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def html_parser(path):

    '''Opens the template.htm and returns it as a bs4 Object'''

    with open(path,'r') as inf:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(inf,'html.parser')
    
    return soup


resource = html_parser('broken.htm')
print(resource)
table = template.findAll('table')[-1]
print(table)
```

EDIT: I have realised that the chars "<" and ">" are being read as ">" and "<". Are those escape chars? How can I read those in properly? Can I just save the file again with a different codec somehow?

Comment: it did work before. the initial htm was created in word, modified in python and then written again. so I know it is possible regardless of whether it was created in word.

Comment: there isn't a `.read()` in my code though...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it and it was surprisingly simple:

I simply copy-pasted the entrie text in notepad++ to a new file and saved it as .txt.
The file looked fine in notepad so I was hopeful that saving it in a new file would fix the encoding issue. Then I just changed the extension to .htm and ran the code again. Easy-peasy.